# Суммирование значений столбца для каждой группы и вывод группы с максимальным значением

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Бьюсь с одной проблемой уже не первый час. У меня есть признак `hour` **часы**(его я создал в скрипте в коде это есть) и есть признак `views` **просмотры**. Мне необходимо определить *действительно ли опубликованные статьи в **12** часов дня набирают больше всего просмотров*? Всего часов у меня в признаке `hour` от 0 до 23.

Выполняю следующие действия:

```
df[(df['hour'] == 12)]['views'].value_counts().max()
```

и мне выдаёт ответ **94**.

Далее выполняю:

```
df[(df['hour'] == 13)]['views'].value_counts().max()
```

и вижу что уже **99**.

Таким образом задачу я решил))) ответил на вопрос что статьи опубликованные в 12 часов дня не набирают больше всего просмотров. Но решил я путем того что вручную менял значение времени в скрипте. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это выполнить без этого ручного перегона? 
Вот весь исполняемый скрипт:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
df = pd.read_csv('howpop_train.csv')  
#Избавимся сразу от переменных, названия которых заканчиваются на _lognorm  
df.drop(filter(lambda c: c.endswith('_lognorm'), df.columns), 
    axis = 1,       # axis = 1: столбцы 
    inplace = True) # избавляет от необходимости сохранять датасет  
#Создадим несколько столбцов на основе данных о времени публикации:  
df['published'] = pd.to_datetime(df.published, yearfirst = True)
df['year'] = [d.year for d in df.published]
df['month'] = [d.month for d in df.published]
df['dayofweek'] = [d.isoweekday() for d in df.published]
df['hour'] = [d.hour for d in df.published]  

#СТРОКА КОДА КОТОРАЯ РЕШАЕТ ПОСТАВЛЕННЫЙ ВОПРОС  
df_mode_public = df[(df['hour'] == 12)]['views'].value_counts().max()  
print(df_mode_public)
```

Comment: Если нужен файл с данными:https://yadi.sk/i/R7PneAsVUa7BiQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) считает не сумму значений, а количество элементов - например, можно посчитать количество троек.

У меня получилось, что статьи опубликованные в 12 часов дня имеют больше всего просмотров. Я использовал ваш код и дальше сгруппировал датафрейм по часам и просуммировал просмотры в каждой группе.

```
views = df.groupby('hour')['views'].sum()
```

Результат:

```
hour
0      71574141
1      55793066
2      39370785
3      28620488
4      22746228
5      14653279
6      22379317
7      27457105
8      40356336
9      82958032
10    128170279
11    160061962
12    177152709
13    171944260
14    165019258
15    151460266
16    156445444
17    136846168
18    124982145
19    105027594
20     95351805
21     83486794
22     86409148
23     82567593
Name: views, dtype: int64
```

И нахождение максимального значения:

```
views.nlargest(1)
```

Результат:

```
hour
12    177152709
Name: views, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Да всё верно. Как оказалось ошибся я намного раньше)) Спасибо вам большое!

Answer (score 2):

@Andrey уже [показал как правильно посчитать top N сгруппированных и агрегированных значений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951208/211923).

Я бы хотел показать как использовать Pandas более эффективно для предварительной обработки данных.

Эффективнее не читать вовсе те столбцы, которые вы впоследствии хотите удалить. Для этого можно сначала прочитать только заголовок CSV файла, отфильтровать столбцы по именам и воспользоваться аргументом `usecols`.

Кроме того можно парсить дату/время "на лету".

```
fn = r'D:\download\howpop_train.csv'

cols = pd.read_csv(fn, nrows=0).columns
cols = cols[~cols.str.contains(r'_lognorm$')]

df = pd.read_csv(fn, usecols=cols, parse_dates=['published'])
```

получилось:

```
In [100]: df.dtypes
Out[100]:
url                    object
domain                 object
post_id                 int64
published      datetime64[ns]   # <---- NOTE
author                 object
flow                   object
polling                  bool
content_len             int64
title                  object
comments                int64
favs                    int64
views                   int64
votes_plus            float64
votes_minus           float64
dtype: object
```

чтобы сгруппировать данные по компоненте даты/времени не обязательно создавать постоянный столбец - можно группировать по вычисляемому значению:

```
In [101]: df.groupby(df['published'].dt.hour)['views'].sum().nlargest(5)
Out[101]:
published
12    177152709
13    171944260
14    165019258
11    160061962
16    156445444
Name: views, dtype: int64
```

если же вам нужны все компоненты даты/времени в качестве столбцов для последующих расчетов, то их можно создать за один вызов:

```
formulas="""
year = published.dt.year
month = published.dt.month
dow = published.dt.dayofweek
hour = published.dt.hour
"""

df = df.eval(formulas)
```

результат:

```
In [109]: df[['year','month','dow','hour']]
Out[109]:
        year  month  dow  hour
0       2008      1    1    18
1       2008      1    1    18
2       2008      1    1    18
3       2008      1    2     1
4       2008      1    2    14
...      ...    ...  ...   ...
134132  2016     10    0    21
134133  2016     10    0    22
134134  2016     10    0    23
134135  2016     10    0    23
134136  2016     10    0    23

[134137 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за такую подробную информацию! Однозначно  вы профессионал! Я бы с большим удовольствием взял бы у вас уроки)!